# If-Modied-Since header makes CORS OPTIONS request fail

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, cors, browser-cache

In the following code custom header (`If-Modified-Since`) makes ajax fail with status `HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed` of `OPTIONS` preflight request. However, if I remove the header, request works well as expected (I am not sure if `OPTIONS` is not sent at all or dev consoles just don't show it). Why is it so? (Same situations with googleapis hosted jquery).

```
http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('GET', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
http.setRequestHeader('If-Modified-Since', 'Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT')
http.send();
```

Also, is there a way to send this header in xhr to jquery cdn to be able to get `304` reponse status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the Web server is saying that it doesn’t allow the `OPTIONS` verb (method). To confirm, check if the response includes an `Allow` header (per the HTTP spec, it should), and if so, what it contains. If it does not include `OPTION`—e.g., if it’s just `Allow: GET, HEAD, PUT`, then your `OPTIONS` request is going to always fail. So if what you want to do relies on that using `OPTIONS`, it’s not going to work with that server.

Per the requirements in the CORS spec, setting the `If-Modified-Since` header (or [any other header except Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language or a few Content-Type cases](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-header)) causes the client to be required to do a preflight; and doing a preflight requires using the `OPTIONS` method. But neither the CORS spec nor any other spec requires that all Web servers actually must support the `OPTIONS` method; and in a case where a Web server doesn’t, I think you’ll get exactly the kind of response you’re seeing here.

Comment: Firefox dev tools show that only `Server`, `Date`, `Content-Type`, `Content-Length`, `Connection` headers are present in response. The point of my question is, 1) why doesn't it work if `OPTIONS` request is a standard thing in cross-domain requests? 2) why does this behaviour change depending on setting If-Modified-Since header?

Comment: 1) It’s not going to work with any server that doesn’t allow the `OPTIONS` method. In this case, the standard defines what the client must send, but it does not require that every Web server must actually allow the `OPTIONS`  method. In cases where a Web server doesn”t support it, you’ll get exactly the result you’re seeing, and that is still spec-conformant.

Comment: 2) Setting a custom "author" header (*any* header added by you as an author other than `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language` or a few `Content-Type` case) makes the request get preflighted (and the preflighting causes the `OPTIONS` method to be used).

Comment: Sorry, it took time for me to study and understand that spec.